# jQuery write value into the input field's "value" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field, input type `text`:

```
<input type="text" id="show-val" value="">
<button id="get-val">Val</button>
```

On button click it's taking a URL from somewhere else, I need to place the value into the text field's `value` attribute.

What I could is:

```
$('#get-val').on('click', function(){
    var url = 'http://example.com/'; //suppose this is our grabbed URL
    $('#show-val').val( url );
});
```

But if you inspect the input text then can see it's not writing the `url` into the `value` attribute, it's just pasting the value into the text field.

What I tried:

```
$('#get-val').on('click', function(){
    var url = 'http://example.com/'; //suppose this is our grabbed URL
    $('#show-val').prop( 'value', url ); //failed
    $('#show-val').prop( 'placeholder', url ); //passed
});
```

Output is:

```
<input type="text" id="show-val" value placeholder="http://example.com/">
```

Why am I failing writing text field's `value` attribute? How can I write actually?

Comment: value is a property so `$('#show-val').val( url );` is correct, However if you want to modify the value attribute the use `$('#show-val').attr( 'value', url );`

Comment: @Satpal please make it an answer. It's THE answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value is a property so `$('#show-val').val(url);` is correct.

However if you want to modify the value attribute the use [`$.fn.attr( attributeName, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.

*Code*

```
$('#show-val').attr('value', url);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function is used to set values for attributes like `checked`, `disabled`. You should use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) or [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) functions for setting values in HTML form fields.

Examples:

```
$('input#show-val').val(url);
```

or

```
$('input#show-val').attr('value', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `value` attribute by -

```
$('#show-val').attr('value', url );
```

But

```
$('#show-val').val( url );
```

also set the `value` but not the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$("#show-val").attr("value",url);
```